# Optimizing function that automatically creates internal links based on post title string

Tags: database, wpdb, performance, optimization

Problem sovled,thank you @SamuelElh for the tip ,so I relect it in the code.Transient turns out to be the right solution.

I wrote a function that adds links to existing post titles that occur in a post. For example, when you add a post to a site with the title "this is a title" and then the phrase "this is a title" shows up in the content of another post, it will automatically link to the previous post that holds that title.

My function works well (except for one thing which I will explain later):

```
function ji_title_auto_link($content){
if (is_single()) {//only auto link on post pages.
    global $post;
    global $wpdb;
 //retrieve all the post titles from the database,and this is where it goes nasty cause I have more than 50000 post!
 // UPDATE:Check for transient. If none, then execute $titledb
 if (false === ( $titledb = get_transient( 'titledb' ) )) {
 $titledb=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
  set_transient( 'titledb', $titledb, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
}

foreach ($titledb as $key) {
    $titles=$key->post_title;//foreach all the titles
    $link=get_permalink();
    $replace='<a target="_blank" title='.$titles.' href="http://12reads.cn/wiki/'.$titles.'">'.$titles.'</a>';
    $titleself=get_the_title();//make sure it don't link itself
    $pos=strpos($content, $titles);
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $length=strlen($titles);
        if ($titles != $titleself) {
            $content=substr_replace($content, $replace, $pos, $length);
        }

        unset($key);
    }
}
//echo get_the_title();
return $content;
}else{return $content;}
 }
add_filter('the_content', 'ji_title_auto_link');
```

The problem with this function is that I have 50,000 plus posts on my site. Imagine that I have to retrieve 50,000 titles from the database using `$wpdb->get_results`. The result is a disaster! It slows down the post page instantly.

My question is how can I rewrite this function to save some database burden or is there even any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Wow, you're selecting the whole titles every time! would be better if you select based on the content, or if you cache `$titledb` (with wp object cache or transients) for future.

Comment: how do I select base on the content? is that possible?? thank you.

Comment: You should intercept post saving and do this job only once. There are approriate hooks activating your code when user clicks Save button.

Comment: you mean 'publish_post'? and wirte the auto link into the database permanently?

Comment: thank you @SamuelElh for the transient tip.Transient API is the solution here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a cache plugin (or write your own custom cache plugin) to server those posts.
2. Set the cache plugin to update posts' contents whenever any other post title is updated / added. Or you can do this in a background process using cron.

This way your original content remains intact, but you still get quick response from the server.

Comment: NO,cache plugin like w3tc is not helping in this case.The right way is what @SamuelElh suggested:using wordpress transient API.Pls see the updates.

Comment: There is no right or wrong ways, there are many ways to do one thing. You can write a simple cache plugin that will cache content of every post/page and the use the_content filter to output from the cache.

Comment: Of course you can use transient API to save the cache of the title query & save the cache of content in post meta. The idea is you cache the results.

Comment: Thing is ,if I use a persist cache plugin, there willl be 50,000 times super slow browsing experience before the cache even work. But if transient,there will only be one.

Comment: Not necessarily. As I said, you can cache the final content with link in post meta & you can use that along with the transient call for titles + use a cron job to update the title result in transient & content cache in meta in the background before they expire - that way you'll not have a single super slow  browsing experience.